# EJB Inyection on abstract class

Tags: java, ejb, abstract-class

i have the following object structure:

```
public abstract class RGBusinessLogic {
    @EJB
    protected RGBeanLocal rgb;

    public abstract String foo(String x, String y);

    public void bar(){
        ...some code...
        rgb.anyFunction(... some params...);
        ...some code...
        foo(someStringX,someStringY);
        ... some code...
    }

    public String bazz(){
        ... some code...
    }
}

@Stateless
public class RGEnqueuerResource extends RGBusinessLogic {
    @Override
    public String foo(String a,String b){
        ...some code...
        wa = rbg.anyOtherFunction(...some params...);
        ...some code...
    }
}

/** that is a Rest Services **/
@Path("somePath")
@RequestScoped
public class RGEnqueuerResourceRest extends RGEnqueuerResource{
    @POST
    @Path("fooRest")
    public String foo(
        @FormParam("paramA") String a,
        @FormParam("paramB") String b){
        return super.foo(x,y);
    }

    @POST
    @Path("bazzRest")
    public String bazz(){
        return super.bazz();
    }
}
```

The main idea is the following design is: I have some code factorized on RGBusinessLogic that inherit multiples class and the other child class implemented the abtract code.

When i get an POST Request on `RGEnqueuerResourceRest.foo`, i get a  `NullPointerException` at line

```
wa = rbg.anyOtherFunction(...some params...);
```

Looks like `rgb` EJB isn't injected correctly. I would like to know if you can find out what is going on here ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using Java EE 6...
RGEnqueuerResourceRest is not a session bean so your RGBeanLocal EJB is not injected. The simplest solution is to annotate RGEnqueuerResourceRest with @Stateless so the bean will be managed by the container and EJB injection will work.